# I need REGEXP for alpha Numeric zip code, which contains minimum 3 & maximum 10 values

Tags: javascript, regex, html

I need REGEXP for alpha Numeric zip code, which contains minimum 3 & maximum 10 values.

- Invalid inputs are: `AAAAA`, `A1`, `AA`, `12`, `2A`
- Valid inputs are: `123456`, `123`, `A1234`, `A12`, `A12A`, `A9A`

This is the regex I'm currently using:

```
/(^[A-z0-9]\d{3,10})+$/
```

It doesn't allow to specify only digits like this `12345` but input like `A123` matches correctly.

Comment: *Values* = *digits*?

Comment: I'm not quite following what you're asking. If you just want to match 3-10 alphanumeric characters, then use `/^[A-z0-9]{3,10}$/`.

Comment: @YOU: the question says *alpha*numericals.

Comment: This question is pretty confusing as written. Could you maybe write example inputs and outputs that do not work as expected?

Comment: Your regex currently says allow a number or letter as the first character, then allow 3-10 numbers. You state `it is not allowing only number`; so get ride of `[A-z0-9]`. I'm also not sure what the trailing `+` is for at the end of the expression.

Comment: i want input like this 123456, A12A, A12. those are valid input & also  input must be in between min 3 & max 10

Comment: if i am giving only numbers like 12345 it is showing error msg enter valid zip code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not completely clear. If you mean that you can use *between 3 and 10* characters, and these characters can be alphanumerical characters (digits and `[A-Za-z]`), you can use:

```
/^(?=.*\d.*)[A-Za-z0-9]{3,10}$/
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/gO0jZ7/2).

The regex works as follows:

- `^[A-Za-z0-9]{3,10}$` says the regex consists out of `3` to `10` characters that can be digits and/or `A-Z`/`a-z`.
- The lookahead `(?=.*\d.*)` enfoces that the string contains at least one digit somewhere in the string.

Comment: not useful it is taking only alphabets also that i don't want

Comment: @MaheshKalyankar: as commented before, your question is very unclear, please reformulate it.

Comment: @MaheshKalyankar: and furthermore all the provided inputs are validated by the regex... Please give a counterexample.

Comment: invalid- AAAAA, A1, AA, 12, 2A,

Comment: valid- A1A, A12, 21A,123,123456, 2A1

Comment: @MaheshKalyankar: so there must be at least digit in the string?

Comment: yes only digit is valid but only alphabet is not valid for my purpose

Comment: @MaheshKalyankar: see updated answer, all your examples match/don't match with regex101...

Comment: @MaheshKalyankar: is lowercase enabled?